# Preserve letter order when replacing LTR chars with RTL chars in a word at byte level

Tags: python, unicode, hebrew

I have a Hebrew word "יתꢀראꢁ" which needs to be "בראשית". To correct I am encoding and than replacing chars. The replacement works however since I am replacing LTR chars with RTL chars the order gets jumbled.

```
data="יתꢀראꢁ".encode("unicode_escape")
data=data.replace(b"ua880", b"u05e9")
data=data.replace(b"ua881", b"u05d1")
data=data.decode("unicode_escape")
print(data)
```

Instead of "בראשית" I get "יתשראב"
Replacing chars on a byte level is my only option. How do I preserve the order after the replacement

EDIT:*The garbage text comes from here https://777codes.com/newtestament/gen1.html after a scrape. While I understand it is best to avoid fixing this kind of mess scraping and replacing missing chars seems to be the only solution. My sample is the first word on that page. Any suggestion on how to get the Hebrew text correctly with a straight scrape is most welcome but I doubt this is possible. The garbage in this case are placeholder chars which are being rendered correctly by woff fonts.*

Comment: Well, why not just use regex to replace the chars?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm rather confused by this input. How exactly did you end up with characters used for a dialect of Gujarati, in the middle of the Hebrew text?

Comment: I am rather awkward with regex but if you sir can assure me the order will be conserved I will work that out and implement. If it fails I will update the question with my regex attempt

Comment: To be clear, when you say what the output needs to be, do you mean that that is the intended order of characters (and that you've written it left-to-right to match the English explanation)? Or do you mean that that is the intended appearance of the text? Which should be the first character in the result string - `ב`, or `ת`?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I need to scrape a html page which uses fonts to render some characters. Those non hebrew chars are place holders and the correct hebrew letters are rendered by woff. My solution is to scrape first than build a map and manual replace.

Comment: When I try the obvious, straightforward approach `data.replace('\ua880', '\u05e9').replace('\ua881', '\u05d1')`, I get the same result as with your unicode-escape round tripping. I don't know what problem you were hoping to solve with the extra complication.

Comment: Trying to correct mojibake is generally a bad idea. It's preferable to avoid creating mojibake in the first place. So, where does the text `ꢀראꢁ` come from? Who or what is responsible for decoding that text incorrectly?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel This is the page I am trying to scrape. https://777codes.com/newtestament/gen1.html The first Hebrew word on there בראשית comes through as "יתꢀראꢁ" so this crazy dance is to replace and correct the missing characters. A solution on how to get the correct word from a straight scrape will be extremely helpful as well but I doubt that is possible

Comment: It looks like each Hebrew and each Saurashtra (placeholder) part in the text on that page gets wrapped in its own `<div>` tag with an appropriate `ltr` attribute. You can probably make use of this information while parsing the page content.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes that will work but a less complicated way is to make a new array and store hebrew and hebrew corrected letters in sequence.  I am just surprised there is no method to reset letter positioning im a string.

Comment: There are other Unicode values you could insert into the string that might fix the text rendering order, but the BIDI algorithm is *really* complicated. You really just want to filter the data, I'm pretty sure. I just finished writing out an answer.

Comment: The site is using a webfont "PMPFGN+EzraSIL" which is a subseted version of Ezra SIL that contains 23 glyphs in the Saurashtra block. Discrete words are RTL, but lines of text are LTR. I suspect from font name, font and text were extracted from a PDF. Cleaning up large amounts of text would be fairly problematic. Best to use a better source for the Hebrew text.

Comment: The font's character U+A880 is actually U+FB2A from the Alphabetic Presentation Forms block, which maps to the sequence U+05E9 U+05C1

Comment: You have the added complication that the overall environment is LTR, the first string character is LTR, so you have a word mixed with LTR and RTL characters that is rendered LTR overall. So any word starting with a Hebrew codepoint will be treated as RTL (but my have additional embeddings within the word. Any word starting with a Saurashtra codepoint will render LTR overall with additional embeddings within the word. So at least two scenarios when repairing words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Analysis

Let's first look at the data in a form that will be unambiguous and that can be followed by English readers:

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> data="יתꢀראꢁ"
>>> [unicodedata.name(c).split()[-1] for c in data]
['YOD', 'TAV', 'ANUSVARA', 'RESH', 'ALEF', 'VISARGA']
```

Here, the `'ANUSVARA'` and `'VISARGA'` are the placeholder characters, which have a left-to-right text order; the others are Hebrew and have a right-to-left text order. For the sake of clarity, let's use those names (and a couple more) to define some single-character constants:

```
YOD, TAV, ANUSVARA, RESH, ALEF, VISARGA = data
SHIN = 'ש'
BET = 'ב'
```

We seek to replace `ANUSVARA` with `SHIN` and `VISARGA` with `BET`. However, there is a complication: while the logical order of the original characters is `YOD, TAV, ANUSVARA, RESH, ALEF, VISARGA`, they display on screen left to right as `TAV, YOD, ANUSVARA, ALEF, RESH, VISARGA` - that is, with each Hebrew segment reversed, because Hebrew is written right-to-left.

We want the resulting text to appear, left to right, as `TAV, YOD, SHIN, ALEF, RESH, BET`. Since it will be all Hebrew text, the actual order of the characters should be reversed completely: `BET, RESH, ALEF, SHIN, YOD, TAV`.

### Approach

Conceptually, we need to take these steps:

```
YOD, TAV, ANUSVARA, RESH, ALEF, VISARGA
```

Split the text into LTR and RTL components:

```
(YOD, TAV), (ANUSVARA,), (RESH, ALEF), (VISARGA,)
```

Replace the placeholder LTR components with new RTL ones:

```
(YOD, TAV), (SHIN,), (RESH, ALEF), (BET,)
```

Reverse the order of the components:

```
(BET,), (RESH, ALEF), (SHIN,), (YOD, TAV)
```

Join up the string:

```
BET, RESH, ALEF, SHIN, YOD, TAV
```

To split the string, we can use regex:

```
>>> pattern = re.compile(rf'({re.escape(ANUSVARA)}|{re.escape(VISARGA)})')
>>> parts = pattern.split(data)
```

The `parts` will have an empty string at the end; this is of no consequence. Note the capturing group used in the regex: this makes the actual "split" delimiters appear in the `parts` (otherwise we would *only* get the Hebrew parts).

The overall solution fits into a one-liner:

```
>>> ''.join(
...     SHIN if c == ANUSVARA else BET if c == VISARGA else c
...     for c in reversed(pattern.split(data))
... )
'בראשית'
```

The idea is that we use a generator expression to iterate over the `reversed` components, making substitutions as we go. This feeds into `''.join` to join the components back together. Since we are replacing entire components, we don't use `.replace`; we have extracted e.g. the `ANUSVARA` as a separate string by itself, so we do an equality check and conditionally replace with `SHIN`.

### Generalization

To create the pattern for more LTR placeholders, build the regex pattern procedurally. We need a regex-escaped (for robustness) version of each literal that we're searching for, separated by `|` and surrounded in parentheses, thus:

```
def any_literal(candidates):
    """Build a regex that matches any of the candidates as literal text."""
    alternatives = '|'.join(re.escape(c) for c in candidates)
    return re.compile(f'({alternatives})')
```

To do multiple replacements, build a dictionary:

```
replacements = {ANUSVARA: SHIN, VISARGA: BET}
```

and use dictionary lookup for the replacement, defaulting to the original value (i.e., for things which *aren't* placeholders, replace them with themselves):

```
def fix_hebrew_with_placeholders(text, replacements):
    splitter = any_literal(replacements.keys())
    return ''.join(
        replacements.get(c, c)
        for c in reversed(splitter.split(text))
    )
```

Testing it:

```
>>> fix_hebrew_with_placeholders(data, {ANUSVARA: SHIN, VISARGA: BET})
'בראשית'
>>> fix_hebrew_with_placeholders(data, {ANUSVARA: SHIN, VISARGA: BET})[0]
'ב'
```

Comment: Yes this works perfectly! Thank you very much! My dictionary has around 25 entries and it is substituting the placeholder characters with the correct letters the same way the font rendering does. And it is also preserving letter order perfectly

Comment: Although, the character in the text is Hebrew Letter Shin with Shin Dot, rather than Hebrew Letter Shin.

Comment: Hmm? I don't see any dot on `ש`. Or did you mean in the original webpage?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel SAURASHTRA SIGN ANUSVARA in the string also exists in the webpage, the embedded font uses the glyph for HEBREW LETTER SHIN WITH SHIN DOT (FB2A) at the codepoint for SAURASHTRA SIGN ANUSVARA. The original text and font were probably extracted from a poorly generated PDF.  So U+A880 in the text is actually U+FB2A, but U+FB2A is a presentation form, and U+05E9 U+05C1 should be used instead. So U+A880 is U+05E9 U+05C1.

At my count there are potentially 23 glyphs that are assigned incorrect Unicode codepoints.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel the source document is a nightmare, all the text is rendered LTR instead of RTL, and visually laid out within an LTR context, so when you replace the incorrect characters, the string displays RTL, but the order of the characters is LTR, so everything is reversed, if I use bidi override formatting characters, then the string displays correctly, but is wrong in data. One possibility is to force it to be read as a visual sequence, then run a visual to logical algorithm on it. But not sure if that would work once you factor in word order, punctuation. Systemically corrupted data.

Answer (score 0):

My take on the problem:

The website the string is taken from is displaying the Hebrew text as LTR text, the text uses glyphs from the Alphabetic Presentation block that has been reassigned to the Saurashtra block. So we have an overall LTR orientation with a sequence and a mixed script word where Hebrew characters are stored logically within substrings interspaced with LTR characters.

My approach is to:

1. Use a regex pattern to split the string on the Saurashta characters, which should leave the Hebrew substrings in logical order within substrings.
2. Then I reverse the list so substrings are in logical order (rather than putting each character in logical order).
3. Then replace Saurashta characters with the correct Hebrew characters.

There is the added complication that you are working with RTL text so that it is neccesary to work in an environment that has bidirectional support, such as Jupyter Lab, since rendering is handled by the web browser and the UBA is well-supported in web browsers. Printing the string in a terminal/console will incorrectly display RTL strings, complicating the analysis.

```py
import regex
data = "יתꢀראꢁ"
data = "".join(regex.split(r'(\p{Saurashtra})', data)[::-1])
data = data.replace("\ua880", "\u05E9\u05C1").replace("\ua881", "\u05D1\u05BC")
# U+05D1 U+05BC U+05E8 U+05D0 U+05E9 U+05C1 U+05D9 U+05EA
```

Although further testing is needed to ensure the same patterns occur within the rest of the document.

Note that the str.replace() method should be rewritten, since you actually need to be able to handle 23 different replacements. Possibly:

```py
import regex
data = "יתꢀראꢁ"
data = "".join(regex.split(r'(\p{Saurashtra})', data)[::-1])
# data = data.replace("\ua880", "\u05E9\u05C1").replace("\ua881", "\u05D1\u05BC")
substitutions = {"\ua880": "\u05E9\u05C1", "\ua881": "\u05D1\u05BC"}
for char in substitutions.keys():
    data = data.replace(char, substitutions[char])
```

My current hypothesis is that the original document was written with the Ezra SIL font, converted to a PDF file, with an embedded subsetted font (PMPFGN+EzraSIL), the text and font for the website were extracted from the PDF.

**Edited:**

A more complete substitution matching the webfont:

```py
substitutions = {
    "\ua880": "\u05E9\u05C1", "\ua881": "\u05D1\u05BC", "\ua882": "\u05DD", "\ua883": "\u05DC\u05B9",
    "\ua884": "\u05E9\u05BC\u05C1", "\ua885": "\u05E5", "\ua886": "\u05D5\u05BC","\ua887": "\u05DA\u05B0",
    "\ua888": "\u05E4\u05BC", "\ua889": "\u05D5\u05B9", "\ua88A": "\u05DE\u05BC", "\ua88B": "\u05D9\u05BC",
    "\ua88C": "\u05DB\u05BC", "\ua88D": "\u05D3\u05BC", "\ua88E": "\u05DF", "\ua88F": "\u05E9\u05C2",
    "\ua890": "\u05EA\u05BC", "\ua891": "\u05E7\u05BC", "\ua892": "\u05DC\u05BC", "\ua893": "\u05D2\u05BC",
    "\ua894": "\u05E3", "\ua895": "\u05E0\u05BC", "\ua896": "\u05D4\u05BC"
}
```